# error when i create flutter project from android studio

Tags: flutter

i installed all SDK and plugin
when i create flutter project, it alert error that is

error create project:
Could not find an option named "platforms". Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter -h') for available flutter commands and options.

and there is appear add configuration.

like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U49vc.png)

Comment: do you see ``Indexing`` or ``Gradle build`` something at the bottom?

Comment: Did you try it by cmd ?

Comment: I don't see anything else .just this problem >

Comment: when i create project from cmd it run without any problem

Comment: Can you add to question result of `flutter doctor` command from command line?

Answer (score 7):

In android studio terminal type
***flutter upgrade -f***. After the upgrade, create a new flutter project.

More details [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67251#issuecomment-703216477)

Comment: Solved the issue for me. Should be tagged as the good answer. Thanks, really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Got this error as well, to fix I did the flutter upgrade -f, and upgraded my Android Studio to the latest version.

Comment: Heads up!
Your answer is not a complete solution to this question.
When this occurs, you must enter it as a comment.